# initialize STL map with constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a class with STL map and another class as member variables.

Here is my class definition:

```
class demo
{
    map<int, map<int, string> > mymap;

    class temp
    {
        int a, b;
    }

    map<string, pair<string, temp*> > mymap1;

    demo();
    ~demo();
}
```

How do I initialize `mymap` and `mymap1` to `NULL` using constructor. I also want to free up memory used by `temp*` using destructor. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't initialize them to `NULL` because they are not pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not initialize `mymap` and `mymap1` to `NULL` as they are not *pointers*, but *objects*.

If you want to initialize them with some parameters, you should do it in the constructor initialization-list:

```
demo() : mymap(/* initialization parameters */),
         mymap1(/* initialization parameters */) {}
```

You also shouldn't use raw pointers as in `temp*`. Instead use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<temp>`. With smart pointers you don't have to free up any memory as it will be done automatically for you.

All you have to do is change the declaration of your map `mymap1` to:

```
map<string, pair<string, unique_ptr<temp>>> mymap1;
```